# What is differences between 頑張ろう　と　頑張りましょう?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am reading Choukai script and I dont understand what is difference between Ganbarou and Ganbarimashou. Both mean "Lets do our best" ? When to use masshou pattern and rou pattern ?

Answer (score 3):

「頑張りましょう」→「頑張る」＋「ます」＋「う」

「頑張ろう」→「頑張る」＋「う」

「頑張りましょう」≒「頑張ろう」

「頑張りましょう」という表現は敬語（honorific or polite form)です。
「ます」が聞き手に対して丁寧な印象を与えます。集会などで、一人の人間が全体に対し話をするときは、多くの場合丁寧語（polite language)を用います。すごく親しい仲間内では「頑張ろう」という表現を用いることが多いと思います。

※「う」＝“will” （auxiliary verb)

Answer (score 1):

@Horiuchi Junya has a good explanation. Simply put:

> 頑張ろう is the **volitional form** of verbs: "let's [verb]"

> 頑張りましょう is the **polite form** of the volitional form: "let's [verb]" as well.

If you are using the former, it is likely a more informal context, such as something that would be said if you were pulling the giant tug-of-war in Naha, or maybe said at Sports Day.

If you are using the latter, it is a more formal context, such as a boss or manager telling a team to do their best on a project. It can also be used just to be more polite.